# CQ5, xml file vs node created in CQ

Tags: xml, dialog, aem

There are total 9 templates in the code. If I go to page properties of any of this then there is one basic tab of which xml already exists with name tab_basic.xml
Now I have to make a property change for only 4 templates , so I created copy of tab_basic.xml with name tab_basic1.xml and made the changes in the properties.
I gave the path of this tab_basic1.xml in the 4 templates(in dialog.xml)

Now what happening is: In crxde node of tab_basic1 is not getting created automatically. Hence, those 4 pages are not able to fetch any properties.
Why!!!
Please resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check first how the original tab_basic.xml was referenced in the dialog.xml?
I never heard of referencing the XML directly as the dialog.xml gets transformed into nodes in JCR and is only the code representation. The actual dialog is then JSON, so this is how I reference tabs that are strored in separate XMLs in the code:

```
<basic
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
    path="/$PATH_TO_FOLDER/tab_basic1.infinity.json"
    xtype="cqinclude"/>
```